# Shiny R Zip multiple PDFS for download

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am sorry if this too simple... I need to zip a number of generated pdfs for uses to download. I tried to use `Zip` function, but failed with error:

```
Warning: running command '"zip" -r9X "pdfs.zip" "plot_1.pdf" "plot_2.pdf" "plot_3.pdf" "plot_4.pdf" "plot_5.pdf" ' had status 127
Error opening file: 2
Error reading: 6
```

Below is my code and any suggestions are welcomed (based on [shiny app : disable downloadbutton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25247852/shiny-app-disable-downloadbutton?answertab=votes#tab-top)) :

UI.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(
  singleton(tags$head(HTML(
'
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      // disable download at startup. data_file is the id of the downloadButton
      $("#data_file").attr("disabled", "true").attr("onclick", "return false;");

      Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler("download_ready", function(message) {
        $("#data_file").removeAttr("disabled").removeAttr("onclick").html(
          "<i class=\\"fa fa-download\\"></i>Download " + message.fileSize + " ");
      });
    })
  </script>
'
))),
  tabsetPanel(
    tabPanel('Data download example',
      actionButton("start_proc", h5("Click to start processing data")),
      hr(),

      downloadButton("data_file"),
      helpText("Download will be available once the processing is completed.")
    )
  )
))
```

Server UI.R

```
library(shiny)

get_a_pdf_plot <- function(my_i){
      pdf(paste("plot_", my_i, sep=""))
      plot(1:my_i*5, 1:my_i*5,
           xlim = c(1, my_i*5),
           ylim = c(1, my_i*5),
           main = paste("1:", my_i, sep = ""))
      dev.off()
}


shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  observe({
    if (input$start_proc > 0) {
      Sys.sleep(2)
      session$sendCustomMessage("download_ready", list(fileSize= "Ready"))
    }
  })

  output$data_file <- downloadHandler(
       filename = 'pdfs.zip',
       content = function(fname) {
        fs <- c()
        tmpdir <- tempdir()
        setwd(tempdir())
        print (tempdir())

        for (i in c(1,2,3,4,5)) {
          path <- paste("plot_", i, ".pdf", sep="")
          fs <- c(fs, path)
          get_a_pdf_plot(i)
        }
        print (fs)
        zip(zipfile="pdfs.zip", files=fs)
       }
  )
})
```

Comment: Is this on a windows machine?

Comment: @jdharrison Yes, and I have 7 zip installed. Also I will deploy this app to `www.shinyapps.io`.

Comment: Is 7 zip in your PATH status 127 probably indicates the zip executable couldnt be found.

Comment: @jdharrison: Thanks for the suggestion and I added `C:\Program Files\7-Zip` to my PATH but still got the same error...

Comment: Maybe use RTools and the zip contained in there. http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/installer.html and put for example c:\Rtools\bin in your PATH.

Comment: I just re-installed RTools 3.1 and add `C:\Rtools\bin` to my PATH, still the same error...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65394/discussion-between-jdharrison-and-tao-hong).

Answer (score 3):

In `get_a_pdf_plot` you have ommitted the `.pdf`

```
get_a_pdf_plot <- function(my_i){
  pdf(paste("plot_", my_i,".pdf", sep=""))
  plot(1:my_i*5, 1:my_i*5,
       xlim = c(1, my_i*5),
       ylim = c(1, my_i*5),
       main = paste("1:", my_i, sep = ""))
  dev.off()
}
```

In your `downloadHandler` your need to prompt shiny on the download type:

```
 output$data_file <- downloadHandler(
    filename = 'pdfs.zip',
    content = function(fname) {
      fs <- c()
      tmpdir <- tempdir()
      setwd(tempdir())
      print (tempdir())

      for (i in c(1,2,3,4,5)) {
        path <- paste("plot_", i, ".pdf", sep="")
        fs <- c(fs, path)
        get_a_pdf_plot(i)
      }
      print (fs)
      zip(zipfile="pdfs.zip", files=fs)
    },
    contentType = "application/zip"
  )
```

Comment: You may need to run the example in a proper browser rather than rstudio pop-up.

Answer (score 0):

This [gist helped me setup the export](https://gist.github.com/RCura/b6b1759ddb8ab4035f30). It runs out of the box on a Mac. Windows required downloading Rtools and pointing to the zip in Rtools ([from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28228892/download-multiple-csv-files-in-a-zipped-folder-in-shiny)). I've not had problems yet.

`Sys.setenv(R_CMDZIP = 'C:/Rtools/bin/zip')`

The `?zip` documentation mentions "On Windows, the default relies on a zip program (for example that from Rtools". If you point to a zip executable for your favorite zip program I'm sure it'll work similarly (if you don't want to download Rtools).