# Download multiple csv files in a zipped folder in Shiny

Tags: r, csv, shiny

Can someone please point out how I can make this download zip function work in server.R? When I run this, I get the following error:

- [1] "/var/folders/00/1dk1r000h01000cxqpysvccm005p87/T//Rtmps3T6Ua"
- Warning in write.csv(datasetInput()$rock, file = "rock.csv", sep = ",") :
  attempt to set 'sep' ignored
- Warning in write.csv(datasetInput()$pressure, file = "pressure.csv", sep = ",") : attempt to set 'sep' ignored
- Warning in write.csv(datasetInput()$cars, file = "cars.csv", sep = ",") :
  attempt to set 'sep' ignored
- [1] "rock.csv"     "pressure.csv" "cars.csv"

  - adding: rock.csv (deflated 54%)
  - adding: pressure.csv (deflated 42%)
  - adding: cars.csv (deflated 57%)
- Error opening file: 2
- Error reading: 9

  ```
  library(shiny)

  # server.R
  server <- function(input, output) {

    datasetInput <- reactive({
      return(list(rock=rock, pressure=pressure, cars=cars))
    })

    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
      filename = 'pdfs.zip',
      content = function(fname) {
        tmpdir <- tempdir()
        setwd(tempdir())
        print(tempdir())

        fs <- c("rock.csv", "pressure.csv", "cars.csv")
        write.csv(datasetInput()$rock, file = "rock.csv", sep =",")
        write.csv(datasetInput()$pressure, file = "pressure.csv", sep =",")
        write.csv(datasetInput()$cars, file = "cars.csv", sep =",")
        print (fs)

        zip(zipfile=fname, files=fs)
      },
      contentType = "application/zip"
    )

  }

  # ui.R
  ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
    titlePanel('Downloading Data'),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        downloadButton('downloadData', 'Download')
      ),
      mainPanel()
      )
    )
    )

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
  ```

Comment: Solution: Include 'if(file.exists(paste0(fname, ".zip"))) {file.rename(paste0(fname, ".zip"), fname)}' after zip() call.

Comment: Please post your solution as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top solution still wasn't working for me. I was working in RStudio Server on a Linux server. The problem was that RStudio couldn't automatically locate the path to the zip executable. I had to manually specify it. In the command line, `which zip` revealed to me `/usr/bin/zip`.

So, I just had to set the R_ZIPCMD environment variable at the top of my code.

```
Sys.setenv(R_ZIPCMD="/usr/bin/zip")
```

Source: The help file for `zip()` mentions R_ZIPCMD.

Answer (score 3):

Solution: Include `if(file.exists(paste0(fname, ".zip"))) {file.rename(paste0(fname, ".zip"), fname)}` after `zip()` call.